# Rails file download not working in JSON API with devise token authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

After ruining one working day, I am desperate for help.

I have a Rails 4.1.0 application which also exposes a JSON API. In the API I am using devise with token_authentication. There is an Image model with paperclip attachment. While trying to download the image, the postman plugin shows success with status 200. But the image isn't downloaded.

I have tried using both the send_file and send_data method. For both the server shows two log entries. While debugging also, I can see that the 'authenticate_user_from_token' method of ApiController gets executed twice and in the second time the 'X-Auth-Token header' is missing(which is obvious because I am not sending this second request). This results in a 401 Unauthorized error and the file isn't downloaded(See logs at the bottom). I am not sure why send_file or send_data method is causing a second request to server.

Here is my code.

**controllers/api/v1/images_controller.rb**

```
class Api::V1::ImagesController < Api::V1::ApiController

  def download
    @image = Image.find(params[:id])
    # Tried send_file
    send_file @image.pic.path(:original)
    # Tried send_data
    data = File.read(@image.pic.path(:original))
    send_data data, filename: @image.pic.original_filename, type: @image.pic.content_type
  end

end
```

**controllers/api/v1/api_controller.rb**

```
class Api::V1::ApiController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :json

    before_filter :authenticate_user_from_token!
    before_filter :authenticate_user!

    protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

    private

    def authenticate_user_from_token!
        user_email = params[:email].presence
        user       = user_email && User.find_by_email(user_email)

        auth_token = request.headers["X-Auth-Token"]
        if user && Devise.secure_compare(user.authentication_token, auth_token)
          sign_in user, store: false
        end
    end
end
```

**controllers/application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

end
```

**models/image.rb**

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base

  PAPERCLIP_ROOT = "#{Rails.root}/storage"

  has_attached_file :pic, :styles => {:original => "720x720", :medium => "120x120", :thumbnail => "40x40"}

end
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  #API 
  namespace :api , defaults: {format: :json} do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :images do
        member do
          get 'download'
        end
      end

      devise_scope :user do
        post "/sign_in", :to => 'sessions#create'
        post "/sign_out", :to => 'sessions#destroy'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**server_log**

```
Started GET "/api/v1/images/14/download?email=user@example.com" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-21 13:57:25 +0530
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by Api::V1::ImagesController#download as */*
  Parameters: {"email"=>"user@example.com", "id"=>"14", "image"=>{}}
  .
  .
Sent file /Users/rajveershekhawat/workspace/dine_connect/storage/images/pics/000/000/014/original/images.jpg (0.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 14067ms (ActiveRecord: 13.5ms)


Started GET "/api/v1/images/14/download?email=user@example.com" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-21 13:57:40 +0530
Processing by Api::V1::ImagesController#download as HTML
  Parameters: {"email"=>"user@example.com", "id"=>"14"}
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."email" = 'user@example.com' LIMIT 1
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 3462ms
```

Please help. Thanks a lot.

**Update:**

Can somebody tell me why there are two request logs?

Can we even download, an image over json api whithout using Base64 encoding, like a normal download?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `send_data` instead of `send_file`?

You might have to do a read on the paperclip file path.